# Adjoint operator for a system of nonlinear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators, parabolic-pde, self-adjoint-operators

I have this system of nonlinear reaction diffusion equations

$\begin{cases}
& u_t = u_{xx} + \partial_u W(u,v),\\
& v_t = d v_{xx} - \partial_v W(u,v).
\end{cases}$

I found the linearization to it as

$$L = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial^2_x +2 \partial^2_u w(s(x)) && \partial_u \partial_v (s(x))\\
- \partial_u \partial_v (s(x)) && d\partial_{x}^2 - 2\partial^2_v w(s(x)) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I believe that my linearization is right. My question is about the adjoint I found, is it correct? This is the adjoint I found:

**updated**
Let $u(x,t) = \overline{u}(x)  + \varepsilon h(x,t)$, and $v(x,t) = \overline{v}(x) + \varepsilon g(x,t)$. Then it is easy to see that $u_{xx} = \overline{u} + \varepsilon h_{xx}$, and $v_{xx} = \overline{v} + \varepsilon g_{xx}$. Now we write $w(u,v) = w (\overline{u} + \varepsilon h, \overline{v}+ \varepsilon g)$ in terms of $h$ and $g$;

\begin{align} 
    \label{p4eq1} \frac{\partial w}{\partial h}&= \frac{\partial w}{\partial u}\frac{u}{\partial h}=\varepsilon \frac{\partial w}{\partial u} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial w}{\partial u} =\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \frac{\partial w}{\partial h}.\\
\label{p4eq2} \frac{\partial w}{\partial g}&= \frac{\partial w}{\partial u}\frac{u}{\partial g}=\varepsilon \frac{\partial w}{\partial u} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial w}{\partial u} =\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \frac{\partial w}{\partial g}.
\end{align}

Now we find the Taylor series for $w(\overline{u}+ \varepsilon h, \overline{v} + \varepsilon g)$.

\begin{align*}
    &w(\overline{u}+ \varepsilon h, \overline{v} + \varepsilon g) \\
    &= w(\overline{u}, \overline{v}) + \varepsilon h w_h(\overline{u}, \overline{v}) + \varepsilon g  w_g(\overline{u}, \overline{v}) + \varepsilon^2 h^2 w_{hh}(\overline{u}, \overline{v}) + \varepsilon^2 h g w_{hg}(\overline{u}, \overline{v}) + \varepsilon^2 g^2  w_{gg}(\overline{u}, \overline{v})+\dots\\
\end{align*}
Now we find the derivatives $w_u$ and $w_v$

\begin{align*}
    w_h(\overline{u}+ \varepsilon h, \overline{v}+ \varepsilon g) &= \varepsilon  w_h(s(x)) + 2 \varepsilon^2 h w_{hh}(s(x))+ \varepsilon^2 g w_{hg}(s(x))+ \dots,\\
    w_g(\overline{u}+ \varepsilon h, \overline{v}+ \varepsilon g) &= \varepsilon  w_g(s(x)) + \varepsilon^2 h w_{hg}(s(x))+ 2 \varepsilon^2 g w_{gg}(s(x))+ \dots,\\
\end{align*}
using ($\ref{p4eq1}$) and ($\ref{p4eq2}$), and consider terms with order $\varepsilon^1$ we get

\begin{align*}
  w_{u}(u,v)&= 2 h w_{hh}(s(x)) + g w_{hg}(s(x)) \\
w_{v}(u,v)&= h w_{hg}(s(x))+ 2 g w_{gg}(s(x))  
\end{align*}

Now we can express the right hand side of (\ref{p4maineq}) as;

\begin{align*}
     u_{xx} + \partial_u w(u,v) =& h_{xx} + 2 h w_{hh}(s(x)) + g w_{hg}(s(x)),\\
 d v_{xx} - \partial_v w(u,v)=& d g_{xx}- h w_{hg}(s(x))- 2g w_{gg}(s(x)).
\end{align*}

Thus the the linearization operator;

$$L = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial^2_x +2 \partial^2_u w(s(x)) && \partial_u \partial_v (s(x))\\
- \partial_u \partial_v (s(x)) && d\partial_{x}^2 - 2\partial^2_v w(s(x)) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or

$$L = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial^2_x &&0\\
0&& d\partial_{x}^2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \partial^2_u w(s(x)) && \partial_u \partial_v (s(x))\\
- \partial_u \partial_v (s(x)) &&  - 2\partial^2_v w(s(x)) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $U= 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{bmatrix} \in D(L):L^2(\mathbb{R}^2) \to L^2 (\mathbb{R}^2),$ and let
$V= \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}$. Since the diffusion operator is self-adjoint in its domain, we are interested in the second part of $L$;

\begin{align*}
\langle \begin{bmatrix}
2 \partial^2_{u_1} w(s(x)) && \partial_{u_1} \partial_{u_2} (s(x))\\
- \partial_{u_{1}} \partial_{u_{2}} (s(x)) &&  - 2\partial^2_{u_{2}} w(s(x)) 
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix} \rangle
&=\\ \langle \begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
2 \overline{\partial^2_{u_1} w(s(x))} && \overline{\partial_{u_1} \partial_{u_2} (s(x))}\\
- \overline{\partial_{u_{1}} \partial_{u_{2}} (s(x))} &&  - 2\overline{\partial^2_{u_{2}} w(s(x)) }
\end{bmatrix}\rangle\\
\end{align*}

Then,

$$L^* = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial^2_x &&0\\
0&& d\partial_{x}^2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \overline{\partial^2_{u_1} w(s(x))} && \overline{\partial_{u_1} \partial_{u_2} (s(x))}\\
- \overline{\partial_{u_{1}} \partial_{u_{2}} (s(x))} &&  - 2\overline{\partial^2_{u_{2}} w(s(x)) }
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$

If my answers is right How can I find a function $\phi$ such that $L^* \phi=0$ given that $Ls(x)=0$ where $s(x)$ is the stationary solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you considering a stationary solution when trying to find the adjoint of the linearisation? Did you multiply each equation by, say, functions $a$ and $b$ and integrate by parts? Also, what are the bars supposed to represent in $L^{*}$?

Comment: @mattos because it i used it to linearize the operator. I edited my post, i posted my steps. However, I did the steps of finding the adjoint operator on a paper.